# SQL to migrate post types to taxonomy

Tags: categories, mysql, sql

It's been about 5 years since  had to touch a database so please bear with me.

I've just taken over a site that has posts split up by post types, and I need to merge all those posts into the default 'post' post type, and assign each post the former post type name as a category.

I'll be doing the migration directly in the database. I don't have access to the codebase.

In other words:

1. Select all posts of any of the following post types `'tvc', 'tv', 'music_for_radio', 'film', 'mastering', 'recording_and_mixing'`
2. Assign each post's current post type as it's category.

I have minimal experience in relational databases so I'm a bit confused by how I would join all the taxonomy-related tables together to achieve this.

Please help :-)

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't have access to the codebase. ` Do you mean WordPress admin area?, If you could install a plugin I can guide you through a process which makes a duplicate of all posts types as a '**post**' and sets there category to the original post type. It's fairly simple and doesn't require direct database changes.

Comment: @kabiir For the time being the codebase is in another party's ownership, so I need to do this using SQL for now.

Comment: I'm not that good with SQL, wait for other experts on this matter.